# Hide a page from search results in SXA

Tags: sxa, content-search

Is it possible to mark a page as hidden from search results in SXA 1.8 Sitecore 9.0.2?

I have a scope defined where the particular page template is allowed but there are exceptions when I would like to forbid a few of the pages from appearing in the search results. Can this be done without changing the scope itself? From Authors perspective ideally this would be just a checkbox on the page, but I am happy to consider other options.

What is the easiest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Scope

The easiest/fastest way is via scope

[image]
but I see you don't want it.

## Searchable - modification

There is a computed field in SXA named **searchable**.
Based on a base template it adds a field to the index of type **bool**. So later SXA can determine whether an item should be searchable or not.

You could extend it and include an additional check (based on a checkbox)

## New index field - exclude from search checkbox

Similar to previous but this doesn't require direct SXA modification but you will have to create your own field.

Create a separate computed field (similar to `Searchable`) and store information from your checkbox.

Don't forget to use it in your scope.

## Different template - not Searchable

It is not convenient but you could have a separate Page template for excluded pages and make sure that it does not contain **Searchable** base template

## Summary

For single pages, I would use **1st**. If you want to let people control that I would go with **3rd**.

Comment: Hi, may I ask about Scope? I have a parent item and 10 children, I want to hide the parent item only but show the 10 children, is that possible?

Comment: yes, I believe solution is included in my answer.